# Run a rake db:seed multiple times without creating duplicate records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, seeding

I have some code in a seed file that I'd like to alter so that it does not create duplicate records when I run the seed command multiple times. Any way to adapt the code below from my seeds file so that this is possible? The find_or_create_by method doesn't appear to work here unless I am mistaken.

```
data_file = Rails.root.join('db/data/data.csv')

CSV.foreach(data_file) do |row|
  TownHealthRecord.create(
    city: row[0],
    state: row[1],
    country: row[2],
    zip_code: row[3],
    area_code: row[4]
    )
end
```

Comment: why do you think `find_or_create_by` won't work here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a validation. If you don't want duplicate records, validate the uniqueness of one or more fields. In you `town_health_record.rb`

```
class TownHealthRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :city
  validates uniqueness_of :health, scope: :person # If you wanted to validate a combination of fields
end
```

On an added side not, `.create!` will raise errors. `.create` will not. Same goes for `save!` and `.update_attributes!`.